# Word for dangerous semi-knowledge, equivalent of German "gefährliches Halbwissen"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, translation, german

In German, there is a phrase like "dangerous semi-knowledge" *gefährliches Halbwissen*. *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gef%C3%A4hrliches_Halbwissen)* definition:

> a degree of superficial knowledge that becomes dangerous or deceptive because it has one trust one’s own amateurish judgment

I can't think of any equivalent in English. Any ideas?

Comment: Dangerous superficial knowledge!

Comment: That's one of the senses of "common knowledge" -- "facts" that aren't true but are commonly accepted by far too many people.

Comment: I have deleted my answer after posting on SE German Language. It turns out that  "Halbwahrheit" exists, and is the obvious equivalent of "half-truth", whereas there is no equivalent  single English noun to "Halbwissen".

Answer (score 5):

In English, we'd say that someone who behaves in that way exhibits the ***[Dunning-Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect)***: from Wikipedia, "In popular culture ... a claim about general overconfidence of people with low intelligence", although as the article points out, the original paper discussed competence in a professional environment rather than generally.

We might also say that they "know just enough to be dangerous", although that isn't really a stock phrase.

There's also a well-known quotation:

> A little Learning is a dangerous thing

Alexander Pope, *[An Essay on Criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Essay_on_Criticism)* (1711).

Comment: Pope's original quote is probably better known as: [a little knowledge is a dangerous thing](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/a-little-knowledge-is-a-dangerous-thing.html?expand_article=1)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A There doesn't seem to be a great difference in their idiomaticity. I learned the 'learning' variant.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth that's probably because you were born in an age where trains ran on steam... :P P.S I'm not far behind.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A You're a tender?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Very funny, yes. I might be described as looking like a tank :)

Comment: On a side note. Germans often use it as a disclaimer to say they are aware their understanding or knowledge might be limited

Comment: @PortreeKid English doesn't really have a stock phrase to express that.  You could say something like "superficial knowledge" or "knowledge only of the basics", but there isn't one phrase that everyone would use.

Comment: @PortreeKid - The disclaimer here is 'as far as I know' for competent people; incompetent people totally believe in themselves.